# Font styles are not working properly in java using PDFBox while converting PDF to Image

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox for converting pdf to image. Here I'm facing an issue with font. while converting pdf to image I could see the below warnings in my log

```
Using fallback font LiberationSans for Helvetica-Bold
Using fallback font LiberationSans for Helvetica
Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Courier-Bold
Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Courier
```

because of this issue the font styles are not working properly. In PDF I have set the Bold font but after converting it into image its not showing as Bold font.

But the same code is working in my local machine which is **Windows** and not working server environments (application is running in Docker container, which is **centos rhel fedora**).

**Please find the below code which I'm using**

```
boolean isDoubleSide =false; //this is method parameter
try (PDDocument pdDocument = Loader.loadPDF(new File("path/to/pdffile"))) {
    PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(pdDocument);
    for (int page = 0; page < pdDocument.getNumberOfPages(); ++page) {
        //Setting DPI as 203 for the image
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, 203);
        String imageFileName = (isDoubleSide ? Paths.get("path/to/imagefile", random_str + "_" + (page + 1) + ".jpeg").toString() :
                Paths.get("path/to/imagefile", sOutFileNameBase + ".jpeg").toString());
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpeg", new File(imageFileName));
    }
}
```

I'm using latest pdfbox version - 3.0.1

Attaching the PDF and Image for the reference

**This is PDF screenshot**
[image]

**This is converted Image**
[image]

you can see the font is not properly displaying in Image. Please suggest some solution for this. Thanks.

**Update**

I have installed the fonts in the Container and tried that conversion, but still I could see the warnings in logs. In the below location that fonts are installed
**/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/**
Attaching the screen shot
[image]

Comment: You need to add the fonts to the server.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer Can you please provide the details like how to add that fonts in server or share any reference If you find?

Comment: Depends on the OS of the server, which you have told us about.

Comment: Make sure the fonts Arial, Courier, Times, Symbol and Zapf-Dingbats are on your system.

Comment: I have installed the msttcorefonts in that container, but still its showing the Warning. fonts are stored under this location /usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/. I have updated the questions with fonts screen shot.

Comment: open the file .pdfbox.cache in your user home directory with an editor. Are the new fonts there?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I could see there is a /home directory in that container, but it is empty

Comment: call `System.getProperty("user.home")` and output the result and then look in that directory. "/home" is not the user home directory. The user home is usually something like "/home/myname" or "/user/myname" depending on the OS.